# Ionic Geolocation Permission issue on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3

I have a problem with the [GeoLocation Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/) at ionic3.

I added all the import stuff. The `<edit-config>` part too. I can see this in my plist file:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Get Position</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Get position</string>
```

So I think it works. But it doesn't; it works for Android but not for iOS.
I call this method:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
    alert("geo " + resp.coords.latitude);
    // resp.coords.latitude
    // resp.coords.longitude
   }).catch((error) => {
     alert(error.code);
     alert(error.message);
   });
```

I got the Error.code 2 and the Error.message: "Origin does not have permission to use Geolocation service".

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact problem -- I had to manually add this privacy setting in the *.plist file in XCode itself (found in resources/).

Under `Key` you type `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description`, or at least start typing it, and it will autocomplete. `Type` should be `String` and `Value` should be the message you want to popup to the user explaining why you need access to location data.

Comment: Okay, it works. Again. But with a setTimeout function. Is it possible that my code runs faster then the GPS is ready?

Comment: Do you have something like this when you're trying to get the location?
`this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((pos) => {
      this.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
      console.log('Successfully got location');
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });`

Comment: Yes and I get the Error. When I set a timeout, it works and the Values are displayed.

Comment: Maybe try removing and readding the platform?
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/geolocation-plugin-not-working-code-based-off-of-docs-example/119288

Comment: But it works now. I added the privacy key like you said and it works :)
The Iphone asks for a Geolocation Permission. But if i run the Function without a timeout, it will give me an error. But if i wrap a setTimeout, i got my longitude and latitude value.

Comment: You should not manually edit the settings in Xcode. It will be removed when you re-add your platform. This is not the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used Ionic v4 with React, Cordova v9, cordova-ios v4.5.5. The problem in my case happened because I didn't inject the Cordova JS script to the webview. To fix it, I added the following Bash script to Cordova's before prepare hooks (`(cordova root)/hooks/before_prepare/inject_cordova.js`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
sed -E -i "" -e "s_(<head[^>]*>)_\1<script src=\"cordova.js\"></script>_" www/index.html
```

Where `www/index.html` is the path to your application main HTML file relative to the cordova project root.

The last line adds a `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` tag to the end of the HTML file when you run `cordova prepare ios`. As a result, the webview starts loading the Cordova scripts including the geolocation plugin and the application starts asking a permission to use the geolocation.